# quantstrat (2016.3.11 version) demo luxor.4 warning message

Tags: quantstrat

I have installed the latest quantstrat from source, previous error with luxor.4 is gone, but still got a warning message as follows:

```
Warning message:
In data.frame(forex.1 = list(param.combo = list(EnterLong = 1L,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

run `sessionInfo()` returns the following:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[6] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doMC_1.3.4                   
 [2] iterators_1.0.8              
 [3] quantstrat_0.9.1709          
 [4] foreach_1.4.3                
 [5] dplyr_0.4.3                  
 [6] blotter_0.9.1695             
 [7] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
 [8] FinancialInstrument_1.2.0    
 [9] quantmod_0.4-5               
[10] TTR_0.23-0                   
[11] xts_0.9-7                    
[12] zoo_1.7-12                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3       codetools_0.2-14 
 [3] lattice_0.20-33   assertthat_0.1   
 [5] grid_3.2.3        R6_2.1.2         
 [7] DBI_0.3.1         magrittr_1.5     
 [9] robustbase_0.92-5 tools_3.2.3      
[11] DEoptimR_1.0-4    compiler_3.2.3
```

I am new to R, I cannot verify whether this warning is trivial or not. Could anyone give me some advice on this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest from R-Forge?

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, I cannot get connected to stackoverflow from China for a few days.
I am not able to install using e.g. `install.packages("FinancialInstrument", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. I did install the latest packages with source package .tar.gz

Comment: I just re-installed all packages with the latest version. luxor.4 did work. Thanks Joshua

Comment: No worries for the late reply. I'm glad it works for you now.

Comment: Though luxor.4 is working now, I still got Warnings as follows

Comment: Edit your question and include the warnings. Adding them as comments will make them hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I edited the question above. As the error was corrected by updating packages, now the question is all about the warning. (this is the first time I tried to edit question, I hope I did it in the right way. )